# A construction for a complex value function question.

Tags: complex-analysis

This question is a little bit confusing to me. Say, here we have a continuous function from $C$ to $C$:

$f(z) = e^z$ for all positive real number z and

$f(z+w) = f(z)*f(w)$ for all (complex) numbers.

Then the question asks me to find (prove the existence of) a complex number $v$ such that for all complex number $z$ we have $f(z) = e^{z+v*(Im (z))}$.

The question also gives a hint to let me notice the function $e^{-z}*f(z)$.

I made several trying of potential $v$ values but don't get the desired answer. I started with let the $f(z)$ multiple some combination of $v$ whose overall value is 1 so that it may lead to the desired requirement but failed.

Comment: I think this requires continuity of $f$.

Comment: Yes, Sorry, I forget to mention, it is a continuous function from C to C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can show that $f(x)=e^{x}$ holds for all real numbers $x$. [I will let you supply a proof].

Let $g(y)=f(iy)$ for $y$ real. Then $g(a+b)=f(ia+ib)=f(ia)f(ib)=g(a)g(b)$. Since $g$ is continuous this implies (by standard result) that $g(y)=e^{cy}$ for some $c  \in \mathbb C $. Hence $f(x+iy)=f(x)f(iy)=e^{x} g(y)=e^{x}e^{cy}=e^{x+c y}$ so we can take $v=c$.

Comment: Sorry, I just want to make sure that if the f(x+y)=fxfy can still lead to the fx = c^x for complex continuous function...

Comment: @qwerty I should have written $e^{cy}$ with complex $c$ instead of $c^{y}$ with $ c>0$. I have edited my answer.